# Reading comma delimited file using SAS

Tags: sas

**Raw file to be read using SAS has following records:**

123,"Harold Wilson",Acct,01/15/1989,$78,123

128,"Julia Child",Food,08/29/1988,$89,123

007,"James Bond",Security,02/01/2000,$82,100

828,"Roger Doger",Acct,08/15/1999,$39,100

900,"Earl Davenport",Food,09/09/1989,$45,399

906,"James Swindler",Acct,12/21/1978,$78,200

**SAS CODE :**

```
options nocenter;

filename file1 'D:\files\SAS\raw-files\employee.csv';

data Employ;
infile file1 dsd;
input id       :       $3.
      name     :      $20.
      depart   :       $8.
      datehire : mmddyy10.  
      salary   :  dollar8.  
      ;
format datehire mmddyy10.
       salary    dollar8.;
run;

title 'Employee details';

proc print data=Employ;
run;
```

**OUTPUT**

Employee details

Obs     id          name         depart      datehire     salary

1     123    Harold Wilson     Acct        01/15/1989         $78

2     128    Julia Child       Food        08/29/1988         $89

3     007    James Bond        Security    02/01/2000         $82

4     828    Roger Doger       Acct        08/15/1999         $39

5     900    Earl Davenport    Food        09/09/1989         $45

6     906    James Swindler    Acct        12/21/1978         $78

**ISSUE :**

How to get the salary in the same format as in the raw file as the salary part after the comma is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If you created this CSV file yourself, you should create it again.  SAS sees the comma in the data value as a field separator (as would any other application).

If you cannot re-create the file, you can read the two columns as different text variables, concatenate them with a comma, and "read" the result using the INPUT function:

```
data Employ;
   infile file1 dsd truncover;
   input id       :       $3.
         name     :      $20.
         depart   :       $8.
         datehire : mmddyy10.
         salary_a :       $8.
         salary_b :       $8.
         ;
   salary = input( catx(',',salary_a,salary_b),dollar8.);
   drop salary_a salary_b;

   format datehire mmddyy10.
          salary    dollar8.;
run;
```

Notice the `truncover` option is added to your `infile` statement.  This is important to allow SAS to properly handle the last variable (salary_b).

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Bob's excellent answer above you could also do:

```
 data test;
  infile cards dsd truncover;
  input id name & : $20. depart : $12. datehire anydtdte10. salary comma8.;
  format id z3. datehire mmddyy10. salary dollar8.;
  cards;
  123,"Harold Wilson",Acct,01/15/1989,$78,123
  128,"Julia Child",Food,08/29/1988,$89,123
  007,"James Bond",Security,02/01/2000,$82,100
  828,"Roger Doger",Acct,08/15/1999,$39,100
  900,"Earl Davenport",Food,09/09/1989,$45,399
  906,"James Swindler",Acct,12/21/1978,$78,200
  ;
  run;

  proc print;
  run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution to my problem that is to use **ampersand(&)** while reading **salary variable** instead of **colon(:) modifier** and without using **truncover**

```
data Employ;
    infile file1 dsd;
    input id       :       $3.
          name     :      $20.
          depart   :       $8.
          datehire : mmddyy10.  
          salary   &  dollar8.  
          ;
    format datehire mmddyy10.
           salary    dollar8.;
run;
```

**ampersand(&)** will continue to read the salary variable until two comma delimiters are encountered.Hence, the file can be read correctly.